# ReferenceError: connestionString is not defined at E:\mongodb_lesson3\app.js:5:47 at Object.<anonymous> (E:\mongodb_lesson3\app.js:13:7)

Tags: mongodb

> Написал код как у автора видео. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
let client = require ('mongodb').MongoClient; // client объект для присоед и работы с базой; 'mongodb' драйвер; MongoClient методы дл ясоед с БД выполнения запросов и др операций
const connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017"; //адресс для подключения к MongoDB
(async () =>{ //асинхронный метод (для чего асинхронный)?      
        let connection = await client.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser:true});  //как бы переменна для подключения к БД               
        let db = connection.db('usersdb');  //если базы с таким названием нет то она просто создастся и мы будем с ней работать
        try{
            let user = {name:'Ivan', age:25};
            const result = await db.collection('users').insertOne(user);           
            console.log(JSON.stringfy(result));       
        }finally{             
            connection.close(); //соединение закроется независимо будет ошибка или нет       
        }   
    })().catch(error => console.log(error));





/*
Полный текст ошибки
ReferenceError: conneсtionString is not defined
    at E:\mongodb_lesson3\app.js:4:47
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\mongodb_lesson3\app.js:14:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
*/
```

Comment: Код нужно вставлять текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 0):

> После переустановки Mongo на системный диск ошибка исчезла

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]>